# In Ruby, can I have a Struct within a Struct?

Tags: ruby, struct, liquid

I want to code the following logical structure:

> ```
> category
>   name
>   description
>   fields
>
> field
>   name
>   description
> ```

I'm using liquid drops for this. So if I have:

```
class FieldDrop < liquid::Drop
  def initialize(field)
    @field = field
  end
  def name
    @field.name
  end
  def description
    @field.description
  end
end
```

then how do I get the CategoryDrop class to reference the FieldDrop within its `def fields` method?

My struct is:

```
Category = Struct.new(:name, :description, :fields)
```

based on the CategoryDrop where

```
def fields
  @category.fields
end
```

I want `def fields` to expand into @field.name + ' ' + @field.description for each field.

Comment: What do you mean "struct within a struct"? Ruby doesn't exactly have structs.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Not sure this is what OP wants, but Ruby does have structs. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Struct.html

Comment: Ah, I see. I had seen those before but forgotten. I was thinking about C-style structs.

Comment: Based upon your naming I am left wondering: does each Category have potentially more than one `Field`? So are you looking for a list or collection of `Struct` within a `Struct`, not just a `Struct` within a `Struct`?

Answer (score 2):

By the naming, and description of your question, it sounds like you are wanting a collection or list of `Struct` within another `Struct`, not just a `Struct` within a `Struct`.

Define a `Category` struct:

```
Struct.new('Category', :name, :description, :fields)
 => Struct::Category
```

Define a `Field` struct:

```
Struct.new('Field', :name, :description)
 => Struct::Field
```

When you create a `Category` instance, it can have an array for the `fields` member, which might originally be empty:

```
@category = Struct::Category.new('Foo', 'This is a foo', Array.new)
=> #<struct Struct::Category name="Foo", description="This is a foo", fields=[]>
```

Then add some fields to `@category`:

```
@category.fields << [ 'Field 1', "This is field 1" ]
@category.fields << [ 'Field 2', 'This is field 2' ]
...
```

Then your fields display method could look like:

```
def fields
  @category.fields.each { |f| puts f.name + ' ' + f.description }
end
```

Or whatever you wish to do with the fields.

Comment: @user962915 you're very welcome. If you find my answer acceptable, if you could be so kind as to check the "accept" check mark to indicate your acceptance, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.